# Variable Selection of Linear Regression via Simulated Annealing

Tags: regression, self-study, feature-selection, simulated-annealing

I am dealing a problem currently about the simulated annealing.

The problem is:

> $$Y = β_1X_1 + β_2X_2+ \dots + β_{1000}X_{1000} +
>  \epsilon,\ \epsilon ∼ \mathcal{N}(0, σ_2) $$ We take the Residual Sum
> of Squares (RSS) as the loss function in this linear regression
> problem with simulated annealing. Please ﬁnd the best linear model
> with only three explanatory variables. In other words, only three out
> of $β_1, \dots,  β_{1000}$ are non-zero.

I know the details of simulated annealing and know how to implement it. But what do ***best linear model*** and ***explanatory variable*** mean? I try to choose three maximum values of $\beta$ each time but the final result differs each time. So what is the criterion of *best*? Is there anything I am missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please explain what the operation "$+\gt$" is intended to mean?  BTW, your question is directly answered in the quotation: "best" means a model with the *lowest* RSS value (among those with at most three nonzero coefficients).

Comment: @whuber I am sorry that I did add an additional "$>$" in the formulation. But each time the $3$ components with lowest RSS values are different.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "each time"?  You seem to be referring to some kind of repeated process.  Is it possible you are trying to ask [this question?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444544)

Comment: @whuber I use 0 as initialization stage. And choose three maximum values of $\beta$ in each iteration of the simulated annealing until convergence. But when I run simulated annealing algorithms for several times, I get different answer each time.

Comment: That's the very nature of simulated annealing: it is not guaranteed always to converge to an optimal solution.  The theory shows that with a suitable annealing schedule and many iterations, you are highly likely to converge to some near-optimal solution.  There may be a huge number of such local minima.

Comment: @whuber Yes, I understand there may exist a huge number of local minima. But if each time I run the simulated annealing and acquire different answers. How to find *best linear model with only three explanatory variables*?

Comment: As I tried to explain, simulated annealing isn't even intended to do this: it's intended only to come close to the best fit.  In general, the only sure way to find the very best fit(s) is to try all $\binom{1000}{3}=166,167,000$ of the possible models.  In practice, you can rapidly winnow down the possibilities worth checking by using an Elastic Net.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your reply. I understand your point now. Thank you very much!

Comment: Whuber's recommendation of using elastic net as a starting point is not correct. If you used those variables in the model from the post, the p-values would be invalid.