# Why does my cross_val_score give different values when I run it again?

Tags: python, cross-validation, scikit-learn

I'm practicing testing multiple models on the iris dataset with python and I have the following code:

```
for name, model in models:
    # kfold
    kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=7, shuffle=True)
    # score
    score = cross_val_score(model, X_test, y_test, cv=kfold, scoring='accuracy')
    # Add results
    results.append(score)
    names.append(name)
    msg = "%s: %f" % (name,score.mean())
    print(msg)
```

Every time I run this I get slightly different results for the `score.mean()` can anyone explain to me why this happens and how to reduce the variability of the results.

I'm new to machine learning so any help would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Isn't your cross-validation *supposed* to be random and doesn't randomness imply there will be variation from one instance to another?

Comment: Yes, so is there a way to reduce the variability? Or do I need to take the result multiple times and calculate an average?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86522.  I believe https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444544 may answer the question you posted.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365938 might also be relevant.

Comment: You could just set your random seed. In R, that would be `set.seed(7*11*13)`, and there must be some way in Python.